# How to create asyncio ssl datagram endpoint?

Tags: python, ssl, python-asyncio, datagram

I do not understand at what point and in what way to make the connection ssl. context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True) and ssock.accept in connection_made or loop.start_tls...

```
import socket
import ssl
import asyncio


class MyProtocol(asyncio.DatagramProtocol):

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        pass

    def datagram_received(self, data, client_address):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    address = ('', 11111)
    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile='iotivitycloud.crt', keyfile='iotivitycloud.key')

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    sock.bind(address)
    transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(
        loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
            lambda: MyProtocol(), sock=sock))
    loop.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable TLS over UDP you need to install DTLS library `python3-dtls`.

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import ssl
from socket import AF_INET, IPPROTO_UDP, SOCK_DGRAM, socket
from ssl import SSLSocket
from typing import Optional, Tuple

from dtls import do_patch


do_patch()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MyProtocol(asyncio.DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self, on_con_lost: asyncio.Future) -> None:
        self.on_con_lost = on_con_lost

    def connection_made(self, transport: asyncio.BaseTransport) -> None:
        logger.debug("Connection opened")
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(
        self, data: bytes, addr: Optional[Tuple[str, int]]
    ) -> None:
        logger.debug("Received: %s", data.decode())

    def connection_lost(self, exc: Optional[Exception]) -> None:
        logger.debug("Connection closed")
        self.on_con_lost.set_result(True)


async def create_udp_tls_socket(address: Tuple[str, int]) -> SSLSocket:
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)
    ssock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)
    ssock.bind(address)

    return ssock


async def main() -> None:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    address = ("", 11111)
    sock = await create_udp_tls_socket(address)

    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    transport, protocol = await loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
        lambda: MyProtocol(on_con_lost=loop.create_future()),
        sock=sock,
    )

    # Simulate the reception of data from the network.
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(transport.sendto, b"test-msg", address)

    try:
        await protocol.on_con_lost
    finally:
        transport.close()
        sock.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```